# bulkCopy.WriteToServer does not copy

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

I'm trying to use `bulkCopy.WriteToServer()` to copy data from my remote SQL Server Express to my local SQL Server Express, but no data is ever written to my local SQL Server Express database.

The code jumps over the `WriteToServer()` method instantly... I have no idea if it's failing on the inside and not showing an error message though

I have read [How to duplicate a SQL Server 2000 table programatically using .NET 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542296/how-to-duplicate-a-sql-server-2000-table-programatically-using-net-2-0) and I am using very similar code. Although I am using SQL Server 2008 Express on remote and a local to SQL Server 2014 Express:

```
using (SqlConnection remoteConnection = new SqlConnection(remoteConnectionString))
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table'";
    SqlCommand commandGetTables = new SqlCommand(query, remoteConnection);

    try
    {
        remoteConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader results = commandGetTables.ExecuteReader();

        while (results.Read())
        {
            tables.Add(results.GetString(2));
        }

        results.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        remoteConnection.Close();
    }

    remoteConnection.Open();

    foreach (var table in tables)
    {                    
        // Get data from the source table as a SqlDataReader.
        var commandSourceData = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table + ";", remoteConnection);
        var reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

        using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString))
        {
            destinationConnection.Open();

            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table;

                try
                {
                    // Write from the source to the destination.
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //stuff
                }
                finally
                {
                    //stuff removed for this post
                }
            }
        }
    }

    remoteConnection.Close();
}
return true;
```

I know this could be subject to SQL injection etc, but this app is only used by me and not the issue here.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I checked the value of  reader (`var reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();`) and it has entries as I would expect, meaning he reading from the remote is fine.

Comment: What error message do you get? The code, if this is the real code under test, throws away error messages.

Comment: No error messages. I have break points inside all my catch statements which write logs. @MatthewMartin

Comment: You didn't provide mapping

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri      The column positions in the source data reader match the column positions in   the destination table so there is no need to map columns. Is this not correct?

Comment: What do your **connection strings** look like? Does any one of them contain the notoriously tricky `AttachDbFileName=...` clause by any chance??

Comment: @marc_s, the local (destination) is  `Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;  Trusted_Connection=True;  Initial Catalog=HitAnalysisBackUp;` the remote is `Data Source=173.248.XXX.XXX,1533\\sqlexpress;  Network Library=DBMSSOCN;  User Id=myId;  Password= passwordHere;  Initial Catalog=MyTable;" 
`

Comment: Why do this in C#? You could create a stored procedure that copies the data using BCP Utility, Bulk insert or runs an SSIS package created from the Import/Export feature. Then run the stored procedure from C#.

Comment: @CodeSlinger, I don't think I can run the SSIS package as I'm on Express. I'm doing this in C# so in the future I can add new databases in a GUI, such as IP, userId, Password, Initial Catalog etc and then back these up as well... I can try to move this to a SP though

Answer (score 1):

```
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table;
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
```

these lines are wrong it's supposed to look like this..

```
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo." + DataTable.TableName; 
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable);
```